# Wordpress show bad the php hour and date

Tags: functions, date

For my surprise today i see wordpress put bad the hour

In settings i have the hour of my country , France and City Paris

And today i try for create one function the php date function for show the date

```
<?php
echo date("dmY");
?>
```

For my surprise as i tell until , see wordpress change my php time and put day 19 and change the hour and no show the real time actually

If the same code insert in other site - no use wordpress - and the date show right , day 20

How it´s possible wordpress change native function of php and show when runnning this thedate of php , by other side in settings of wordpress i se utc different hour to local time , utc show 19 and local time show 20

I don´t understan all this .....

Thank´s for the help

Answer (score 1):

Did you go to `Settings >> General` and set the correct offset for your timezone?

**To get the date**:
`<?php $date = get_the_time('dmY', $post->ID); ?>`

**To print the date**:
`<?php the_date('dmY'); ?>`

Both need to be within the Loop!

Comment: the problem it´s with setting of wordpress and need change the line 36 for show right the date() core funtion of php : //date_default_timezone_set( 'UTC' );
if ( !function_exists( 'date_default_timezone_set' ) )
date_default_timezone_set( 'UTC' );

Comment: @fran : no, the right answer ___is not___ to hack a core file.

Comment: I think that no hack the code , those words no agree for me , only access to the wp-settings no touch all core and if you know the core you know this right , wordpress it´s very good but in this case for me yes it´s necessary change this line of code because i have one script writte by me and i can´t change all script for one line and because wordpress no let some as the core of php works fine